# airbyte ETL ,connection between http API source and big query

Tags: google-bigquery, etl, connector

i have a task in hand, where I am supposed to create python based HTTP API connector for airbyte. connector will return a response which will contain some links of zip files.
each zip file contains csv file, which is supposed to be uploaded to the bigquery

now I have made the connector which is returning the URL of the zip file.

The main question is how to send the underlying csv file to the bigquery ,
i can for sure unzip or even read the csv file in the python connector, but i am stuck on the part of sending the same to the bigquery.

*p.s if you guys can tell me even about sending the CSV to google cloud storage, that will be awesome too*

Comment: There are two available options to upload data to BigQuery in Airbyte one is called [Standard](https://docs.airbyte.io/integrations/destinations/bigquery#uploading-options) and the other is called [GCS Staging](https://docs.airbyte.io/integrations/destinations/gcs).

Comment: Hey Josh , are you saying that , I can read and send the CSV data through the response of api connector and that can be uploaded to BQ... Like I just want to know how to trasfer data from my source which is giving json response to the big query

Comment: you should consider the answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building an Airbyte source connector with the CDK your connector code must output **records** that will be sent to the destination, BigQuery in your case. This allows to decouple extraction logic from loading logic, and makes your source connector destination agnostic.

I'd suggest this high level logic in your **source** connector's implementation:

1. Call the source API to retrieve the zip's url
2. Download + unzip the zip
3. Parse the CSV file with Pandas
4. Output parsed records

This is under the assumption that all CSV files have the same schema. If not you'll have to declare one stream per schema.
A great guide, with more details on how to develop a Python connector is available [here](https://docs.airbyte.io/connector-development/tutorials/cdk-tutorial-python-http).

Once your source connector outputs `AirbyteRecordMessages` you'll be able to connect it to BigQuery and chose the best loading method according to your need (Standard or GCS staging).